# How to make a serializer for multiple users (student & teacher)?

Tags: python, django, database, rest, django-rest-framework

Hello I am very new to Django Rest Framework and I am having a hard time with the serializer. I extended the User Model using Abstract User. I inserted two new fields which are is_student and is_teacher then I set both of the values to false as default. I then put them in there own model then just applied a one-to-one relation for each of them to the user model. My problem is with the serializer. How do I make a serializer out of this. I want the student and teacher have relation with the user model as well as having the ability to do http actions such as get, post, put, etc.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    course_teaching = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. teacher_obj.user should return the user object related to that teacher obj.

Answer (score 0):

Check out an example of this type of serializer here: https://github.com/imagineai/create-django-app/blob/master/todoapp/serializers.py